# Take substring of text of node using only xPath

Tags: html, xpath, xpath-1.0, instant-view

Input node something like:

```
<span>   01.02.2019 - 31.12.2099      <span>
```

I want to get `01.02.2019` (with whitespaces left or not).

xPath 1.0 only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing the closing tag, try this expression

```
normalize-space(substring-before(span,'-'))
```